# Create a class and init from main game offSet

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

I'm working on my game and i'm having such a hard time wrapping my head around a concept maybe you can clarify it for me.

So in the bullet class i create a bullet object at point 0,0 which is fine
then when i really create it from the main game i create it at point

thePlayer.position.x, 0

Which puts it on the X axis where the player is and 0 on the Y axis which is the bottom of the screen

My issue is lets say i want to create the bullet at the top of the gun for example. not at the base of the screen.
so i would write thePlayer.position.x,60; it would start it at the top of the gun but there would be a offset of 60 till it hits the target...
i did come up with a solution but i don't like it. I think there has to be a better answer..

my answer is:
make a var call bulletOffet=any number lets say 60
then create the bullet at
thePlayer.position.x, 0+bulletOffSet

now when i check i the bullet and the target

for (Bullet *someBullet in self.children) {
        if ([someBullet isKindOfClass:[Bullet class]]) {
            CGPoint bulletPoint = CGPointMake(someBullet.position.x, someBullet.bulletSprite.position.y+bulletOffSet);

this does work but again there has to be a better solution
let me know what i'm missing
thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your problem should be able to be fixed by changing the anchor point of your bullets.

I think understanding anchor points will help you with your issue. I attached a link below that gives a pretty good guild to how anchor points work.

http://www.qcmat.com/understanding-anchorpoint-in-cocos2d/

Comment: thanks for the great read..but my problem is not from the bullet class if i do bulletSprite.anchorPoint=ccp(.5,.5);
        [bulletSprite setPosition:CGPointMake(0,300)]; The bullet will be at the correct position of 300 on the y axis i want to make to go up 300 on the y axis from the mainGame class when i create a bullet object